# PSEXEC write in new instance

Tags: powershell, batch-file, console-application, stdin

I am a beginer in dev in new enterprise.
I use Psexec to open a new instance of CMD (with sdial)
I try to write inside but this is not working, look picture and code for to be clear

```
psexec.exe -d -i -s cmd /c "echo toto & sdial &echo toto"
```

[image: sdial instance]

I want write "toto" like this picture (i have typed with keyboard but i want write "toto" with bat or powershell)

[image: what i want]

in taskmanager I have sDIal.exe in command line (maybe can help you)

[image: sdial.exe]

How to write inside cmd window call "sDial" with bat or powershell ?

last edit
@mklement0 rep to my ask sucessfully

Now i try to register in txt but this is not working

```
psexec.exe -d -i -s cmd /c "echo toto | sdial" >> output.txt
```

there is not txt file ...

Comment: Your task is unclear, an image on a third party site is not good practice, less so when it doesn't help to explain your inadequate question. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57733438/edit) to explain in a better way what you want the code to do.

Comment: So, in an attempt to better explain things, you though you'd post two more images on external sites, despite my previous comment telling you that it is bad practice. We also need to know more about `sDial.exe`, because we have no idea how it accepts command input, _(a quick Google shoes no pages, so it is clear that this is a bespoke/self-made/non distributed executable)_. I have decided due to your lack of useful information, to vote for this question to be closed. If you edit it to provide sufficient opportunity for us to replicate your issue, I will consider retracting that vote.

Comment: @Compo: The gist of this question is: how do I provide automated input (via stdin) to an interactive console application? But that is indeed not exactly. The images are hosted at http://stack.imgur.com/, which is tightly integrated with the SE network: it is where images are automatically hosted when you paste / upload images while asking / answering a question - see  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/ Of course, images alone aren't enough, and they should always be rendered _inline_, but that's easily fixed by placing `!` before the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to provide input to an interactive prompt that program `sdial` presents.

You can try to *pipe* (`|`) this input to `sdial`:

```
psexec.exe -d -i -s cmd /c "echo toto|sdial"
```

Comment: last thing, I search to register the outpout interactive prompt  in txt file. I try `>>output.txt` but this is not work

Comment: @guillaumezac: I don't know what `sdial` is, but I'd try `cmd /c "echo toto|sdial >>output.txt"`; note that `>>output.txt` must be part of the `"..."` command string. Also note that  the startup directory for `sdial` will be `C:\Windows\System32`.